# Ansible loop with additional filters

Tags: loops, ansible

I have the following list

```yaml
ids: [id1, id2, id3]
```

and the following registered result of an iteration

```yaml
  output2:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      failed: false
      item: id1
      msg:
        json:
          key1: '0'
          key2: '6'
          key3: '4'
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      failed: false
      item: id2
      msg:
        json:
          key1: '2'
          key2: '6'
          key3: '6'
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      failed: false
      item: id3
      msg:
        json:
          key1: '8'
          key2: '0'
          key3: '9'
    skipped: false
```

How can I create the dictionary below and select the keys?

```yaml
    "id1": {
       "key1": "0",
       "key3": "4"
           }
    "id2": {
       "key1": "2",
       "key3": "6"
           }
    "id3": {
       "key1": "8",
       "key3": "9"
           }
```

Comment: Show `output2`.

Comment: Hi Jack, it is a pretty much big output, so I'm not sure will I be able to paste it, but let me try, at least for 2 or 3 loop cycles. Thanks.

Comment: The answer shows you what a [mre] looks like. The query should help you understand how to approach your problem.

Comment: I thought that there might be a quick fix/solution without the need for you or anyone else to reproduce and test it. Let me see how can I make it MCVE. I may create completely new question so this one can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I did it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the below variables in *vars*

```yaml
    ids: [id1, id2, id3]
    _values: "{{ output2.results|
                 json_query('[].msg.json.{key1: key1, key3: key3}') }}"
    result: "{{ dict(ids|zip(_values)) }}"
```

As a hint, create the task below for testing. Select *key1* and *key3* from the resulting JSON

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ stat|from_yaml }}"
      register: output2
      loop: "{{ ids }}"
      vars:
        stat: |
          json:
            key1: "{{ range(10)|random }}"
            key2: "{{ range(10)|random }}"
            key3: "{{ range(10)|random }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _values:
    - {key1: '0', key3: '5'}
    - {key1: '1', key3: '9'}
    - {key1: '3', key3: '6'}
```

```yaml
  result:
    id1: {key1: '0', key3: '5'}
    id2: {key1: '1', key3: '9'}
    id3: {key1: '3', key3: '6'}
```

Fit the query according to the content of your *output2*.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ids: [id1, id2, id3]
    _values: "{{ output2.results|
                 json_query('[].msg.json.{key1: key1, key3: key3}') }}"
    result: "{{ dict(ids|zip(_values)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ stat|from_yaml }}"
      register: output2
      loop: "{{ ids }}"
      vars:
        stat: |
          json:
            key1: "{{ range(10)|random }}"
            key2: "{{ range(10)|random }}"
            key3: "{{ range(10)|random }}"

    - debug:
        var: output2
    - debug:
        var: _values|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I didn't mention it because I didn't want to complicate it further, but it looks like it is needed. ID values are actually dynamic list. So, before this task I have a task that gather a list of ID's, so today it can be 10 ID's, tomorrow 20, day after 5... So id1,id2, id3 which I used just as an example list should be the real values (real ID's) from the list. First ID (volume ID), should correspond to the volume information (capacity..) in the first loop cycle, second ID to the second, and so on. Thanks.

Comment: You don't understand. Nobody is going to solve your problem if you don't provide a clear [mre]. [edit] your question and get rid of the complex lists (~20 items of 20-30 characters keys!). Create minimal case `{key1: A, key2: B, ...}` The same is valid for the `id` list. The source (api, uri) is irrelevant. Your case must be reproducible.

Comment: Hi, I took a deeper look and you actually solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK -- given that `output2`, this task will create `foo`:

```
- name: Build list
  set_fact:
    foo: |-
      {
      {% for item in output2.results %}
         "{{ item.item }}": {
                 "key1": "{{ item.msg.json.key1 }}",
                 "key3": "{{ item.msg.json.key3 }}"
          },
      {% endfor %}
      }
```